# Numpy: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: numpy, dimensions, valueerror, negative-number

Using GeFolki for the coregistration of different satellite datasets I receive the following ValueError trying to manipulate the data.

Could you explain what am I doing wrong? Please Help me

```
from skimage.transform import resize
nx = int(round(dimx/fdecimation)) 
ny = int(round(dimy/fdecimation))
Mg = resize(Master,(nx, ny),1,'constant')
nsx = int(round(dimxn/fdecimation)) 
nsy = int(round(dimyn/fdecimation))
Sg = resize(Slave,(nsx, nsy),1,'constant')       

# Rank computation and Criterion on images after deximation
from rank import rank_sup as rank_filter_sup
from rank import rank_inf as rank_filter_inf
Mg_rank = rank_filter_inf(Mg, rank) # rank sup : high value pixels have low rank
Sg_rank = rank_filter_inf(Sg, rank)

R=np.zeros((nx-nsx-1,ny-nsy-1)); 
indices=np.nonzero(Sg_rank);
test2=Sg_rank[indices];

for k in range(0,nx-nsx-1):
    for p in range(0,ny-nsy-1):
        test1=Mg_rank[k:k+nsx,p:p+nsy];
        test1=test1[indices];
        test=(test1-test2)**2
        R[k,p]=test.mean(); 



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-bebe7595123d> in <module>
     17 Sg_rank = rank_filter_inf(Sg, rank)
     18 
---> 19 R=np.zeros((nx-nsx-1,ny-nsy-1));
     20 indices=np.nonzero(Sg_rank);
     21 test2=Sg_rank[indices];

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently one of `nx-nsx-1`,`ny-nsy-1` is negative, but you cannot create an array of 0s with negative number of rows/columns. I suggest printing out those values and see where they get negative to fix it.

Comment: Well it really depends on what you are trying to achieve with creating R and your whole objective. I would recommend checking what you want R to be and how to use it, so that you can fix the dimension to be a correct one.